# Я насчёт метки "еилиё"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

Предлагаю разделить слова и заменить метку на "е-или-ё". Так, на мой взгляд, и читается лучше.

Answer (score 2):

Сделано!

Спасибо за предложение :)

Comment: Отлично! И Вам спасибо! ;)